Not all objects appear in a row during export
I am adding designs to a png in Inkscape 1.3.1 and some designs remain outside the png, for example. I want to export only the part visible in png but it does not export the designs on it. I don't want to group it because I only need the remaining image in png. I want to click on an empty part of the PNG and export it with the remaining objects on it. Even though the Export selected only option is not clicked, I cannot succeed. Is there any other setting? Thank you.

ermm.. huh? Slow down and explain realizing no one here sees anything you are doing.

You cannot insert new items to an existing PNG file by exporting from a new vector drawing. Exporting to an existing PNG file deletes the old version of the PNG and the new version contains only the last exported items. Combine different PNG files for example in GIMP. It can in theory be done also in Inkscape, but it's  easy to change the resolution of the old items, so use GIMP.

If I understand (not sure...) : you have a png, you want to add other png over it and export all images keeping the boundaries of the first png, so that some of the added pngs would be "clipped" when exporting them ?
Provided we are not dealing with png's background transparency issues, I would place the pngs over the original png, then select the original png and do file > export (ctrl+shift+E), choose selection Tab and verify that export selected only option isn't enabled and export.
